# Gmail Api - List Messages Without a Specific Label

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 within a c# project and I am getting a list of messages via the Users.Messages.List(...) function. Before executing the call to Google, I also set the Q property to query the search. However, the query is not functioning as I expect, as it seems to ignore all label references.

Reading through Google's reference docs, I expect to be able to use any query string that Gmail UI accepts.

I have used the following two Q property strings.

```
request.Q = "from:(email@email.com) subject:(Specific Subject Search has * in it) has:nouserlabels has:attachment";

request.Q = "from:(email@email.com) subject:(Specific Subject Search has * in it) -label:specific-label has:attachment";
```

I have also tried using the labelId for the specific label and it does not work either.

These query strings return all the messages that satisfy only the from: and has:attachment properties. It does not seem to matter what I try, regarding the labels (has:nouserlabels or -label:specific-label or -label:labelId).

I can use these queries directly within the Gmail UI and it returns results as expected.

Does anybody have success filtering messages with labels? I am trying to exclude a certain label.

Comment: try testing it out in the gmail application the string you send in Q is the same string that is built in the gmail web app.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the Q strings in Gmail (mail.google.com) UI directly and it returns the search results as expected, filtering with labels. Using the API, the Q property doesn't seem to use the label properties to exclude.